# How to get ASUS A320m mainboard drivers for Ubuntu 18

Tags: drivers

Can anyone tell me where do I get either generic Linux X64 drivers for ASUS A320M mainboard for ubuntu 18.04 version?  The ASUS site doesn't seem to have such a link.

Comment: Drivers for what exactly? Most of common components are already supported by the latest kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Asus, indeed, does not provide drivers for any OS other than Windows.

Comment: I am using ASUS A 320 EX  AMD ryzen 1600 ( 6 core 12 thread) happily since 1 year w/o issues,  all my hardware - wifi usb dongle,  wifi keyboar and mouse, graphics card, monitor sound etc. worik perfectly  99.9% you may not need a driver other than the ubuntu 18/19 bootable DVD/USB that you installed from .  Ee usb3 works off the base OS ihstalled